# Uniquely identify a smartphone from NFC

Tags: nfc, uid

I would like to be able to recognize users by having them just place their smartphone on my NFC reader without having to install any app.

I don't need their smartphone to send any information other than *something* that allows me to distinguish their smartphone and map it to other information that the customer will give me expressing their consent.

Basically, I need the NFC reader to receive *something* that is always different for different smartphones, and always the same for the same smartphone (i.e. it does never change)

Comment: Howabout BLE sensor?

Comment: Not possible without Apps and your reader behaving like a Tag really, NFC implementations are usually specifically designed to prevent this type of tracking (Android is specifically designed to prevent it, I'm sure iOS is as well but there is less info on this). You could possibly use something like a loyalty card feature/ticket of Android/iOS wallets for this with something like Passkit but the user would still have to "install" that to their wallet before use.